# Invalid effective address error when providing offset into buffer

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

I get an invalid effective address from the below, but I don't understand why. I've included the variable/constant definitions for clarity.

```
TurnTreeBuff:   resb 455    ; TurnNum (1 byte) + MT (16 bytes) + PM (16 bytes)
                            ; + BoardState (2 bytes) = 35 bytes * 13 turns = 455 bytes

TURNTREEREC equ 35          ; Turn tree record length

mov byte [TurnTreeBuff+ebx*TURNTREEREC],bl  ; copy turn # to TurnTreeBuff <-error here
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The scale factor in the address can only be 2, 4 or 8 (or 1, which is what you get if you don't specify a scale factor). You're trying to use a scale factor of 35, which isn't supported, so you get an error.

You can read more about addressing in [Intel's manuals](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processors/architectures-software-developer-manuals.html?iid=tech_vt_tech+64-32_manuals). For example, the section named *"Specifying an Offset"* (section 3.7.5 in my copy of the manual).